# LINQ queries to fetch first and last name

Tags: linq, vb.net

I have these two queries and they work just fine.  I use the values they retrieve to populate a title for a view in my application.  It seems though that I should be able to accomplish this with one query and I do not know how.

```
Dim firstName = (From row In db.ItemDetails
    Where row.Unique_Location_ID = locationID And row.Item_Type_Identifier = 1 And _
    row.Category_Attribute_Identifier = 2
    Select CStr(row.Value)).FirstOrDefault()

Dim lastName = (From row In db.ItemDetails
    Where row.Unique_Location_ID = locationID And row.Item_Type_Identifier = 1 _
    And row.Category_Attribute_Identifier = 3
    Select CStr(row.Value)).FirstOrDefault()

ViewBag.assignedTo = ("Employee this item is currently assigned to: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ".")
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [group by clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx) to create an aggregated list constrained by `Unique_Location_ID` and `Item_Type_Identifier`. To make the query more readable, store the names in local variables using the [let clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531379.aspx).

```
Dim name As String = (
    From row In (From r In db.ItemDetails Where r.Unique_Location_ID = locationID And r.Item_Type_Identifier = 1 Select r)
    Group row By row.Unique_Location_ID Into rows = Group
    Let firstName = (From row In rows Where row.Category_Attribute_Identifier = 2 Select CStr(row.Value)).FirstOrDefault()
    Let lastName = (From row In rows Where row.Category_Attribute_Identifier = 3 Select CStr(row.Value)).FirstOrDefault()
    Select String.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName).Trim()
).FirstOrDefault()
```

I also advice you to **not use** underscores in public members as suggested in the [.net general naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx). So, if possible, rename the members to `UniqueLocationID`, `ItemTypeIdentifier` and `CategoryAttributeIdentifier`.